# Fontsetup - switch fonts

Tags: luatex, fontsetup

I use LuaLatex and I load

```
\usepackage{fontsetup}
```

Everything works fine.

My question, which I didn't find anywhere: how can I switch between fonts?

For example, I just want to write a sentence in a different font.

Is there a command to switch the font?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot write a proper answer since I am on mobile. For changing the font of the whole document you simply pass the font option to fontsetup. ex. `usepackage[libertinus]{fontsetup}` will change the fonts of the whole document, according the documentation. For changing fonts in between a document, you can use `setmainfont`, `\setmathfont` and `\setsansfont` commands.

Comment: Fontsetup documentation for various choices of fonts: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontsetup/doc/fontsetup-doc.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your fast response

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the one (main) font defined by `fontsetup`.

But you can define new font families to change the font in the middle of the document.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex 

\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\RequirePackage{ebgaramond}

\newfontfamily{\Garamond}[%
UprightFont=*-Regular,%
Extension = .otf,%
ItalicFont=*-Italic.otf,%
BoldFont=*-SemiBold.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic.otf,%
]{EBGaramond}

\RequirePackage{xcharter-otf}
\newfontfamily{\XCharter}[%
Extension = .otf,%
UprightFont=*-RegularCondensed,%    
ItalicFont=*-ItalicCondensed.otf,%
BoldFont=*-SemiBoldCondensed.otf,%
BoldItalicFont=*-SemiboldItalicCondensed.otf,%
Scale=MatchLowercase
]{CabinCondensed}


\begin{document}
    
    \section{Default (main font)}
    This package is a simple wrapper-type package that makes the setup of fonts easy and
    quick for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. You just load the package using one of the supported
    fonts as an option.     
    
    \section{EBGaramond bold italic}
    
    {\Garamond \bfseries \itshape The target is to provide easy access to fonts with a matching Mathematics font available in
        TeX distributions plus a few commercial if available.}
    
    \section{Default again}
    
    The package will include more font combinations in the future, however there are
    some restrictions. The fonts must have some commercial-level quality and must support
    Mathematics.
    
    \section{CabinCondensed}
    
    {\XCharter  Starting with version 1.01 the package is split in two; the main package called ``fontsetup''
        and the fontsetup-nonfree package that contains the support and sample files for the
        non-free fonts. This facilitates the installation for users of texlive since the latter does not
        install the support for non-free fonts. For a user who wants to install the support for
        non-free fonts (Cambria, Lucida, Adobe-Minion, MS-Garamond, and Linotype-Palatino) it can be
        easily done following the guide for the contrib repository here}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: b]

I found the package documentation a bit misleading. It sounds like it is changing fonts in the middle of the document when it is actually loading independently generated PDF images.

Comment: Thanks! How about if I load fontsetup and use computer modern as font. Like \usepackage[default]{fontsetup}. Now I want to activate a font without serifs. Is that possible? Something like \begin{SFFont}{phv}.

Comment: @honky If the new font is of different family you need to define a new family and the command to activate it. See my example of CabinCondensed

Comment: Thanks again. Which is the right command, if I want to activate "sans serif" for my actual (let's say again  \usepackage[default]{fontsetup}) font family? E.g. for typesetting the titlepage without serifs.